# about drawing sinus function in gnuplot when it is pressed a keyboard

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to draw sinus function on the interval: [-2*pi, 2*pi] in the following way:

when I press right arrow on the keyboard to produce sinus function on the interval: [-2*pi, -pi]

when I press again to plot sinus function on the interval [-pi, 0]

....

Is it possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot something when hitting a key, you must use the `bind` command, like

```
clear
bind Left 'plot sin(x)'
```

The `clear` opens an empty plot windows, which you must then give the focus, and then hit the arrow-left key to plot a sine.

Now you can put more logic into the command which is called in bind:

```
clear
i = 0
left_lim(n) = (i%2 ? -pi : -2*pi)
right_lim(n) = (i%2 ? 0 : -pi)
bind Left 'plot [-2*pi:2*pi][-1:1] (x < left_lim(i) || x > right_lim(i)) ? 1/0 : sin(x); i = i+1'
```

This draw the sine on the interval [-2*pi:-pi] at every odd time you press the key, and on the interval [-pi:0] at every even time you press it. The total xrange is always [-2*pi:2*pi] and the yrange is [-1:1].

Depending on your overall logic (what should happen if you hit the key a third time?) you must adapt this script a bit.